# Find element for button or image

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Not able to identify the object. 
Trying to identify the Button which is in image.
Please let me know how to identify by ClassName or customized XPATH

```html
<div class="schedule">
    <a href="https://link" target="_blank">
        <img border="0" alt="Schedule an appointment" 
             src="https://abcxyz.com/images/cobrand/hvraBookAnAppointment.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Firepath is : //*[@id='mn-wrapper']/div[1]/div[1]/div/a/img

Comment: Try this xpath
    `//a[contains(@href, 'https://link'] `

Comment: I have tried the following xpath and it is working.
//div[@class="schedule"]//img


I have one more doubt : There are multiple buttons of same image & link and want to click on every link.
Please let me know how to click all the buttons from the same web-page with similar xpath.

Comment: Are these links present inside a table?

Comment: No the link is not inside the table. Link is on Header and Content of the WebPage.

Comment: you can use `position()` This is the xpath for second link with same xpath.  `(//div[@class="schedule"]//img)[position()=2]`

Answer (score 0):

This should work-->

//img[@alt="Schedule an appointment"]

OR

//a[@href="https://link"]/img